# Wifi problems on ubuntu intel

Tags: wireless, 20.04, internet

I have frequently problems connecting to the internet with my WiFi card when restarting Ubuntu 20.04

Current Problems :

My hardware can't connect to any WiFi Access Point and after 3 tries, the WiFi button is gone.

Once in a while the connection works for several minutes, then disconnects again.

---

UPDATE : `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; dmesg | grep iwl; iwconfig` output :

```
> 01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
> RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168]
> (rev 15) Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI
> Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:8101] Kernel driver in use:
> r8169 Kernel modules: r8169 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel
> Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81) Subsystem: Intel
> Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 [8086:4010] Kernel modules:
> iwlwifi 03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co.,
> Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01) dmesg: échec
> de lecture du tampon de noyau: Opération non permise lo no wireless
> extensions.
```

enp1s0 no wireless extensions.

`sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` output :

```
> -- Journal begins at Fri 2021-11-26 15:32:36 CET, ends at Wed 2021-12-01 07:15:08 CET. -- nov. 30 20:13:20 enzo-linux systemd[1]:
> Starting Network Manager... nov. 30 20:13:24 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299604.5153] NetworkManager (version 1.30.0)
> is starting... (for the first time) nov. 30 20:13:24 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299604.5154] Read config:
> /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf,
> 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run:
> 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi> nov. 30 20:13:25
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299605.3644] bus-manager:
> acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" nov. 30
> 20:13:25 enzo-linux systemd[1]: Started Network Manager. nov. 30
> 20:13:25 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299605.4598]
> manager[0x5612ab79e030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory
> '/lib/firmware'. nov. 30 20:13:25 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299605.4598] monitoring ifupdown state file
> '/run/network/ifstate'. nov. 30 20:13:26 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299606.1443] hostname: hostname: using
> hostnamed nov. 30 20:13:26 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299606.1444] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to
> "enzo-linux" nov. 30 20:13:26 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299606.1449] dns-mgr[0x5612ab78e170]: init: dns=systemd-resolved
> rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved nov. 30 20:13:26
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299606.1461] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi
> radio killswitch (at
> /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1)
> (driver iwlwifi) nov. 30 20:13:26 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299606.1464] manager[0x5612ab79e030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware
> radio set disabled nov. 30 20:13:26 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299606.1464] manager[0x5612ab79e030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio
> set enabled nov. 30 20:13:26 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299606.6262] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory
> (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.30.0/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
> nov. 30 20:13:26 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299606.7963]
> Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager
> (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.30.0/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
> nov. 30 20:13:26 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299606.8516]
> Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory
> (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.30.0/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
> nov. 30 20:13:26 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299606.9437]
> Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory
> (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.30.0/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
> nov. 30 20:13:27 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299607.5278]
> Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager
> (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.30.0/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
> nov. 30 20:13:27 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299607.5283]
> manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi disabled by radio killswitch; disabled by state
> file nov. 30 20:13:27 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299607.5285] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch;
> enabled by state file nov. 30 20:13:27 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299607.5286] manager: Networking is enabled by state file nov. 30
> 20:13:27 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299607.6383] dhcp-init:
> Using DHCP client 'internal' nov. 30 20:13:27 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299607.8303] settings: Loaded settings
> plugin: ifupdown
> ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.30.0/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
> nov. 30 20:13:27 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299607.8304]
> settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal) nov. 30 20:13:27
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299607.8304] ifupdown: management
> mode: unmanaged nov. 30 20:13:27 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299607.8306] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces
> doesn't exist nov. 30 20:13:28 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299608.2683] device (lo): carrier: link connected nov. 30
> 20:13:28 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299608.2688] manager:
> (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
> nov. 30 20:13:28 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299608.2705]
> manager: (enp1s0): new Ethernet device
> (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2) nov. 30 20:13:28
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299608.2733] settings: (enp1s0):
> created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1' nov. 30 20:13:28
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299608.2879] device (enp1s0):
> state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed',
> sys-iface-state: 'external') nov. 30 20:13:28 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299608.6937] device (wlp2s0): driver
> supports Access Point (AP) mode nov. 30 20:13:28 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299608.6945] manager: (wlp2s0): new 802.11
> Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3) nov. 30
> 20:13:28 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299608.6956] device
> (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed',
> sys-iface-state: 'external') nov. 30 20:13:28 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299608.7621] Error: failed to open
> /run/network/ifstate nov. 30 20:13:28 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299608.7678] modem-manager: ModemManager available nov. 30
> 20:13:34 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299614.6958] manager:
> startup complete nov. 30 20:13:46 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299626.5077] agent-manager:
> agent[14341f4a9d78dcec,:1.51/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/127]: agent
> registered nov. 30 20:14:26 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299666.2654] agent-manager:
> agent[4695b9a69dd4d206,:1.78/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent
> registered nov. 30 20:14:53 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299693.8381] manager: (usb0): new Ethernet device
> (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4) nov. 30 20:14:53
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299693.9087] device (usb0): state
> change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state:
> 'external') nov. 30 20:14:53 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299693.9218] device (usb0): carrier: link connected nov. 30
> 20:14:53 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299693.9335] settings:
> (usb0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 2' nov. 30
> 20:14:53 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299693.9372] device
> (usb0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none',
> sys-iface-state: 'managed') nov. 30 20:14:53 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299693.9467] policy: auto-activating
> connection 'Wired connection 2' (9b793c20-b824-33e9-ad60-b24f527d3fb9)
> nov. 30 20:14:53 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299693.9526]
> device (usb0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 2'
> (9b793c20-b824-33e9-ad60-b24f527d3fb9) nov. 30 20:14:53 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299693.9695] device (usb0): state change:
> disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> nov. 30 20:14:53 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299693.9722]
> manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING nov. 30 20:14:53
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299693.9752] device (usb0): state
> change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> nov. 30 20:14:54 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299694.0019]
> device (usb0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none',
> sys-iface-state: 'managed') nov. 30 20:14:54 enzo-linux
> NetworkManager[876]: [1638299694.0034] dhcp4 (usb0): activation:
> beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds) nov. 30 20:14:54
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299694.0520] dhcp4 (usb0): state
> changed unknown -> bound, address=192.168.42.45 nov. 30 20:14:54
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299694.0624] device (usb0): state
> change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state:
> 'managed') nov. 30 20:14:54 enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]:
> [1638299694.1176] device (usb0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries
> (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed') nov. 30 20:14:54
> enzo-linux NetworkManager[876]: [1638299694.1182] device (usb0): state
> change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state:
> 'managed')
```

Responce to –Nmath : I have an Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165 and the "WiFI button" im talking is in the Wireless sub-menu

thanks (my system is french you maybe need an translator)

Ask me anything but please respond

Comment: What is the exact model of the wifi adapter that you have? What wifi button are you talking about?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; dmesg | grep iwl; iwconfig`

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.